# Can data be accessed between two PCs connected to the same TV through a VGA and a HDMI cable?

Tags: security, hdmi, vga

Can data be accessed between two PCs connected to the same TV through a VGA and a HDMI cable?

I have a laptop connected through HDMI to a 1080p smart TV (no antenna) and a desktop (no networking) connected to the same TV through VGA.

Is this desktop 100% guaranteed to be free from access from the laptop?

Comment: You cannot hack a computer with a VGA or HDMI cable.

Comment: @Ramhound don't say that; HDMI has feedback channels and is able to transmit Ethernet in newer versions. There are more than enough ways to think about how a device could be hacked using HDMI.

Comment: @JensErat - So list one.  I feel confortable with the technical correctness of my comment

Comment: Have a look at [this article on DDC-"hacking"](http://www.cupfighter.net/index.php/2012/03/black-hat-eu-hdmi/). Might even work on some VGA-devices. If anything has network access complex protocols and software comes into play. Not expecting security implications with this is rather simple-hearted. There is a [nice introduction into HDMI security on slideshare](http://de.slideshare.net/44Con/what-the-hec-security-implications-of-hdmi-ethernet-channel-and-other-related-protocols-44con-2012).

Comment: Is the question about how to set up a data transfer using a VGA cable?  (Makes no sense to do that.) Or protecting against data access?  (What are you thinking would happen?) These channels transfer data in one direction for the most part.  What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: @KevinPanko I want to know if the data from the desktop can be accessed from the laptop using the HDMI, the TV, and the VGA cables?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, there is no way that the laptop will access the desktop and vice-versa.

Comment: It would be good to explain the statement which does not look credibly without any supporting information. --- In addition the statement is not necessarily valid. Both VGA and HDMI contains digital connections with various communication protocols. The devices could have vulnerabilities and over them you can possibly gain some sort of access though it is very improbable.

Comment: @pabouk I'd love to explore how that data can be routed...

Comment: @SurvMach: It is not IP :))) You have to provide (implement through the vulnerabilities) the "routing" yourself. That is one of the reasons I wrote "it is very improbable".

Comment: @pabouk I might be out of my depth here but do you have any literature on how this is done?

Comment: @SurvMach: If there is a vulnerability most probably it would be a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) one. In some situations buffer overflow allows gaining control of the targeted device then you can implement your communication (protocol) and route the data further. I do not know a good book but you will find a lot of them on this subject.

Comment: Sounds like a potential defcon/blackhat paper opportunity to me. Still, yes it's unlikely but possible.

Comment: @pabouk I cant believe I just found this talk from 30c3. It's right on the money.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZZCY_-Rkcs&list=PLOcrXzpA0W81LOjuTp8XZ2cjD4rjcTIET&feature=c4-overview-vl